# Is there any way to secure an asp.net MVC4 web app against requests from external web sites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this scenario where an external web site is going to send some data over the network to my web app, then I have to process that info and complete a process within my app. After process completion, I need to return to the original external web with some info.

My questions is about security, how do I know that the external site making the request is actually the web site is supposed to make the request? If you can point me in the right direction would be great!

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4.

Comment: The best idea is going to be to share some sort of key with them that they can send with their request. Depending on how specific the external site is, you could also consider limiting the requests by IP (note that the IP can be spoofed so only doing this would not be ideal).

Comment: I would highly recommend using Client Certificates.

Comment: But if I Install a Client Certificate woudln't every request need to have the certificate? and that means that users would have to install the certificate in their browsers @Erik Philips

Comment: A specific example along the lines of @TravisJ suggestion, and perhaps spur more ideas for you to think about, is [JWT](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html). Hth...

Comment: @Daniel You don't install the certificate, the other side does.  Then you can specify per request (method) if it's allowed.  Non-anonymous methods must require the cert.

Comment: If you just want to verify that the requests are coming from your site, why not just use anti-forgery tokens? Certificates are intended for heightened security and could be preemptive overkill

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, certificate authentication best suits. I have got many external clients consuming my service and cert authentication is working as expected.

```
#Mick Wasson has written this post:
```

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api

You can purchase certificates from 3rd party like :

Rapid SSL :https://www.rapidssl.com/index.html

Global Sign: https://www.globalsign.eu/ssl/

Answer (score 0):

The following are available options. **Basic** or **Tokens** might be good choice if your web app is a public web service.

### Basic

The caller adds an HTTP authorization header containing a user name and password. Those values are essentially plaintext, using only base64 encoding for simple obfuscation. This generally requires Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) transport security (i.e., an endpoint
that exposes an HTTPS address) to protect the plaintext user name and password.

### Digest

Provides a fancier method of putting the user name and password in the HTTP header that provides encryption for those values. This is intended to avoid the need for HTTPS.

### Kerberos

Uses an authentication server, such as Windows Active Directory, to provide integrated and seamless credential validation. This is similar to intranet sites on Windows networks that integrate with the domain for user authentication. A lot of internal SharePoint sites use this approach so that a company's users don't have to re-enter their user name and password when they visit the intranet.

### Public-Key, Certificates

Relies on caller-provided certificates to identify a user. This is not very useful in a public web site or service, but it is very appropriate for applications where the users or devices are known. An example of this approach is an internal, portable, device-based
warehousing application for tracking inventory, or maybe a set of iPads used by the sales team. The group of users is relatively small and well-defined within a company's organizational structure. Each user or device is issued a certificate that identifies him (or it) on every call to your site or service.

### Tokens

Largely used when third-party token issuers are involved (e.g., OpenID, OAuth). This relieves your service of the burden of both storing and verifying a user's credentials. Here's how it works (generally speaking):

The caller first verifies the user name and password using a token issuer that your service trusts. Upon successful verification, the token issuer provides the caller with a token. Once the caller has that token, it uses it to call your service. Since your service trusts the issuer that the caller used for credential verification, your service can trust that the token securely identifies the user, and it therefore doesn't have to bother with verifying the user's credentials itself.

***Source:*** [ASP.NET Web API 2: Building a REST Service from Start to Finish](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484201108).